# Как дождаться завершения четырех асинхронных get-запросов?

Tags: python, асинхронность, tornado, http

Есть функция в приложении на пайтон, которая делает четыре get-запроса, затем присваивает их ответы в переменные и дальше обрабатывает эти переменные. Это происходит синхронно. Возможно ли, запустить эти четыре запроса обрабатываться одновременно асинхронно, а затем поставить функцию на "паузу" до тех пор, пока все они не вернут результат? Т.е. фактически написать синхронно асинхронный код.

Приложение на фреймворке Tornado

Comment: код запросов запускается в отдельных тредах. А главный тред, просто вначале запускает их всех и делает join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Небольшой `disclaimer`: вижу `Tornado` и документацию к нему в первый раз)*

- Если я правильно понимаю, то для ваша задача изящно решается [с помощью `tornado.gen,`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html) который использует `futures` для параллельного выполнения `subtask'ов` и синтаксис, основанный на `yield:`

  ```
  @web.asynchronous
  @gen.coroutine
  def perform_requests_and_handle_them(self):
      client = AsyncHTTPClient()

      # В вашем случае здесь будет 4 параллельно
      # выполняющихся операции.
      response1, response2 = yield [client.fetch(url1),
                                    client.fetch(url2)]

      # Здесь вы синхронно обрабатываете результат асинхронно
      # выполненных запросов.
      synchronously_handle_responses(response1, response2)
  ```
- Если документация корректна, то этот код делает ровно то, что вы описали в вашей постановке задачи:

> - Most asynchronous functions in `Tornado` return a `Future`; yielding this object returns its `result.`
> - You can also yield a list of `Futures` and/or `Tasks`, which will be started at the same time and run in parallel; a list of results **will be returned when they are all 
>   finished.**

- Несколько дополнительных референсов по теме:

> - **http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html**
> - **http://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/tornado/gen.py**
> - **http://goo.gl/uF1IV**
> - **http://antroy.blogspot.ru/2007/04/python-coroutines.html**